# Как представить все числа в строке в двоичном виде?

Tags: c++

> На планете Роботов очень не любят десятичную систему счисления, поэтому они попросили Вас написать программу, которая заменяет все встречающиеся в тексте Ю числа на эти же числа, но в двоичной системе счисления.

**Входные данные**

> Единственная строка, состоящая из любых символов. Длина строки не превышает 255 символов. Гарантируется, что во всех числах нет ведущих нулей.

**Выходные данные**

> Выведите преобразованную строку.

Примеры 
**входные данные** 

6^&678JKjdkdl;?.,lk879Pk1kdfl4839 
**выходные данные** 

110^&1010100110JKjdkdl;?.,lk1101101111Pk1kdfl1001011100111

Это мой код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
string str, BinaryReverse, Reverse_part, Binary, str_num;
stringstream container;
int n;

string toBinary()
{
    BinaryReverse = "";
    Binary = "";
    while (n)
    {
        container.clear();
        container << n % 2;
        container >> Reverse_part;                              //ПЕРЕВОД
        BinaryReverse += Reverse_part;                          //В ДВОИЧНУЮ
        n /= 2;                                                 //СИСТЕМУ
    }                                                           //СЧИСЛЕНИЯ
    for (int i = BinaryReverse.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)         //СНАЧАЛА НАХОДИМ ОСТАТКИ, ПОТОМ ПЕРЕВОРАЧИВАЕМ
        Binary += BinaryReverse[i];
    return Binary;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> str;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)                        //ПЕРЕБИРАЕМ ВСЕ СИМВОЛЫ СТРОКИ
    {
        if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')                      //ЕСЛИ СИМВОЛ ЦИФРА
        {
            for (int a = i +1 ; a <= str.size(); a++ )
            {
                if(str[a] < '0' || str[a] > '9' )               //ИЩЕМ КОНЕЦ ЧИСЛА. КОНЕЦ - ЕСЛИ СИМВОЛ СТРОКИ СТАЛ НЕ ЧИСЛОМ
                {
                    str_num = str.substr(i, a - i);             //НАШЛИ КОНЕЦ - ВЫДЕЛЯЕМ ЧИСЛО
                    i = a - 1;                                  //ПЕРЕВОДИМ СЧЕТЧИК НА СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ ПЕРВЫЙ СИМВОЛ
                    break;                                      //И ВЫХОДИМ ИЗ ЦИКЛА
                }
            }
        container.clear();                                      //ПОЛУЧЕННОЕ
        container << str_num;                                   //ЧИСЛО
        container >> n;                                         //ПЕРЕВОДИМ
        cout << toBinary();                                     //В ДВОИЧНУЮ СЧ
        }
        else
            cout << str[i];                                     //ЕСЛИ СИМВОЛ СТРОКИ НЕ ЧИСЛО, ПРОСТО ВЫВОДИМ ЕГО
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Из всех 20 тестов не проходят 10. Причина : Неправильный ответ. Какое исключение я не учел, какой вариант событий - все никак не могу понять. Сдался) 
**Спасибо за внимание**

Comment: очевидная проблема — длинна входных чисел не ограничена размером `int`, вся строка может быть одним 255-значным числом... тут нужна длинная арифметика... ЗЫ: а ещё комментарии очень громко КРИЧАТ — это тоже большая проблема...

Comment: Это я так, чтобы вы поняли что я написал). я не сомневаюсь, что все тут Гуру и поняли бы, но хотелось  упростить задачу. Попробую заменить на long long, а вдруг ))

Comment: Имхо тут нужно использовать онлайн алгоритм, т.е. переводить по мере получения цифр, а потом корректировать, если встречаются ещё цифра. Если пытаться сначала прочитать всё число, то нужна длинная арифметика.

Comment: Но как использовать это (,введение по символу м корректировка)? Я понятия не имею о принципе, как в данном случае преобразовать

Comment: @ВладКовальчук long long - 8 байт = 2^64 = 2^60*2^4 это примерно 16 * 10*18  то есть точно меньше чем 10^20 то есть в десятичной системе счисления числа не более чем из 20 цифр влезут в long long. А у вас 255 цифр.

Comment: У меня не проходит 5 у тебя получилось?